# Histograma por mes en base a una agrupación, en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo que sacar un histograma que cuente el número de viajes por mes. Cada registro es un viaje, y la fecha se obtiene de la columna fechaFin. Para ello estoy intentando hacer un groupby por el mes de fechaFin y contar, pero no sé como aplicar el contador de viajes. Ando alo perdido, creo que lo estoy planteando bastante mal.

```
df_logsFinalizados2019.groupby(['fechaFin']).count()

ax = df_logsFinalizados2019.plot.bar(x="mesFin",y="idCDU",
        figsize = (20, 7), title = "Distribución de los viajes en 2019",
        xlabel = '', ylabel = '', color = 'orange', rot=1, legend = None)
```

Os paso link con el dataframe en csv, por si alguien quiere hacer pruebas.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ipS5FQp7wIt6FSremMCFcgINHU_qdG0t?usp=sharing

Gracias de antemano!

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedo ver el csv así que no sé el formato de tu fecha, pero lo primero que tienes que hacer es convertir los "strings" en fechas. En tu caso tienes que especificar el formato para que la fecha sea convertida adecuadamente

```
import pandas as pd
fechas = pd.to_datetime(df_logsFinalizados2019['fechaFin'])
```

Después puedes acceder al mes usando:

```
meses = fechas.dt.month
```

Después sólo tienes que generar el histograma:

```
meses.hist()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo es hacer que el índice del dataframe sea esa fecha (convertida al tipo `datetime`), pues pandas tiene funciones para remuestrear índices que sean de tipo fecha.

El dataframe se prepararía así:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("logs (2).csv", sep=";", index_col=0)
df.fechaFin = pd.to_datetime(df.fechaFin)
```

Y ahora ya podemos usar `resample()` cada mes ("1M") y pedir la cuenta de registros en cada mes. Para ello podemos quedarnos con una columna cualquiera, como `idCDU`:

```
viajes = df.set_index("fechaFin").idCDU.resample("1M").count()
```

Esta variable es un dataframe de una sola columna:

```
fechaFin
2020-02-29      1
2020-03-31      3
2020-04-30      0
2020-05-31      0
2020-06-30      0
2020-07-31      0
2020-08-31      0
2020-09-30      0
2020-10-31      0
2020-11-30      0
2020-12-31      0
2021-01-31     59
2021-02-28     76
2021-03-31     55
2021-04-30     82
2021-05-31     65
2021-06-30    116
2021-07-31      4
2021-08-31     77
2021-09-30     10
2021-10-31     47
2021-11-30      3
2021-12-31      5
Freq: M, Name: idCDU, dtype: int64
```

que podemos pintar con pandas:

```
viajes.plot(kind="bar")
```

[image: Grafica]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!